# How do I add regression lines to a scatterplot matrix?

Tags: r, console, regression, rstudio, scatter-plot

How do I go about adding regression lines to a scatterplot matrix? I have the following script:

```
NewNEMSIS = read.csv("NewNEMSIS.csv")
library(gclus)
newmatrix = NewNEMSIS[,2:5]
newmatrix.r = abs(cor(newmatrix))
newmatrix.col = dmat.color(newmatrix.r)
area = NewNEMSIS$area
cpairs(newmatrix[which(area=="A"),c('Response','SceneToPatient','TotalScene','TotalCall')], panel.colors=newmatrix.col, gap=.5, main="Scatterplot Matrix of City A Times", ylim=c(0,60), xlim=c(0,60), na.omit=TRUE, )
```

How can I add splined or sloped regression lines to these scatterplots while keeping them in matrix form? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`cpairs` is just a colorized version of the base graphics `pairs` function, and looking at its code you can see that it does accept the regular set of panel functions described and illustrated in `?pairs`. This is a reproducible example (which yours is not):

```
require(gclus)
png();   judge.cor <- cor(USJudgeRatings)
         judge.color <- dmat.color(judge.cor)
?pairs
#Review the panel functions
?cpairs  
cpairs(USJudgeRatings,panel.colors=judge.color,pch=".",gap=.5, 
        upper.panel=panel.smooth)
dev.off()
```

[image]

You should learn to post an example that illustrates the problem. We have no way of knowing what is in that .csv file so showing that you did that operation is useless in understanding what is going on (over an above knowing that the result is a dataframe). It's fine to use examples from the help pages of functions you are asking about.

Comment: Is there a way to overlay the `panel.smooth` with `panel.color`.  I also did the same thing, but got stumbled with this. (plus one)

Comment: If that were the goal you would need to either hack `cpairs` or make a duplicate of the internal function that cpairs passes to `panel` and then give it to either upper.panel or lower.panel.