# Adding a regression line to scatterplot matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a data named "insurance" which contains the following:

```
head(insurance)
  Race Fire Theft  Age Invol Income
1 10.0  6.2    29 60.4   0.0 11.744
2 22.2  9.5    44 76.5   0.1  9.323
3 19.6 10.5    36 73.5   1.2  9.948
4 17.3  7.7    37 66.9   0.5 10.656
5 24.5  8.6    53 81.4   0.7  9.730
6 54.0 34.1    68 52.6   0.3  8.231
```

I want to construct a scatterplot matrix with regression line fitted on each scatterplot. Is there something I need to add to the code `plot(insurance)` in order to achieve it? I've tried entering the code `abline(insurance,col="red")` but nothing showed up.
[image]

Comment: Hi, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194627/how-do-i-add-regression-lines-to-a-scatterplot-matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add regression lines to a scatterplot matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194627/how-do-i-add-regression-lines-to-a-scatterplot-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do it this way:

```
z <- as.matrix(df)
z
class(z)

pairs( z, panel=function(x,y){
  points(x,y)
  abline(lm(y~x), col='red')
  text(0,1.5,labels = paste('R2=',round((cor(x,y))^2,2)) ,col='red' )
})
```

[image]